# Adding Version Control / Numbering (?) to Python Project

Tags: python, version-control

With my Java projects at present, I have full version control by declaring it as a Maven project. However I now have a Python project that I'm about to tag `0.2.0` which has no version control. Therefore should I come accross this code at a later date, I won't no what version it is.

How do I add version control to a Python project, in the same way Maven does it for Java?

Comment: I don't know Maven, but why can't you use some simple version control system not specific to Python (svn, git, bazaar...)?

Comment: I am using SVN, however that's not the equivalent of maven, it's used *with* maven.

Comment: Hm, do you want to see the version in the source file? I don't know if svn has tags that you could use (basically they are at check-out time changed to include what data you want, e.g. version number, author etc), but at least with git you could write a very simple hook for that.

Comment: I think you are talking about "version numbering" and not "version control".  Version control is typically defined as tools that Makis mentions, such as svn, git, hg, bzr.

Comment: Duplicate of <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458550/standard-way-to-embed-version-into-python-package">this question</a>. Short answer, use `__version__`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, maven is a build tool and has nothing to do with version control.  You don't need a build tool with Python -- there's nothing to "build".

Some folks like to create `.egg` files for distribution.  It's as close to a "build" as you get with Python.  This is a simple `setup.py` file.

You can use SVN keyword replacement in your source like this.  Remember to enable keyword replacement for the modules that will have this.

```
__version__ = "$Revision$"
```

That will assure that the version or revision strings are forced into your source by SVN.

You should also include version keywords in your `setup.py` file.

Answer (score 3):

Create a [distutils](http://docs.python.org/distutils/index.html#distutils-index) setup.py file. This is the Python equivalent to maven pom.xml, it looks something like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(name='foo',
      version='1.0',
      py_modules=['foo'],
      )
```

If you want dependency management like maven, take a look at [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools).

Answer (score 3):

Ants's answer is correct, but I would like to add that your modules can define a `__version__` variable, according to [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which can be populated manually or via Subversion or CVS, e.g. if you have a module thingy, with a file `thingy/__init__.py`:

```
___version___ = '0.2.0'
```

You can then import this version in setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import thingy
setup(name='thingy',
      version=thingy.__version__,
      py_modules=['thingy'],
      )
```