# How can I get the version defined in setup.py (setuptools) in my package?

Tags: python, setuptools

How could I get the version defined in `setup.py` from my package (for `--version`, or other purposes)?

Comment: I think this is approximately the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458550/standard-way-to-embed-version-into-python-package .

Answer (score 314, accepted):

### Interrogate version string of already-installed distribution

To retrieve the version from inside your package at runtime (what your question appears to actually be asking), you can use:

```
import pkg_resources  # part of setuptools
version = pkg_resources.require("MyProject")[0].version
```

### Store version string for use during install

If you want to go the other way 'round (which appears to be what other answer authors here appear to have thought you were asking), put the version string in a separate file and read that file's contents in `setup.py`.

You could make a version.py in your package with a `__version__` line, then read it from setup.py using `execfile('mypackage/version.py')`, so that it sets `__version__` in the setup.py namespace.

### Warning about race condition during install

By the way, DO NOT import your package from your setup.py as suggested in another answer here: it will seem to work for you (because you already have your package's dependencies installed), but it will wreak havoc upon new users of your package, as they will not be able to install your package without manually installing the dependencies first.

Comment: This is simply the best answer here: best way is to use execfile if you need setup.py to get the version from your package.

Comment: `execfile` works really well... but (sadly) doesn't work with Python 3.

Comment: ... OK, for Python 2 *and* 3 use `with open('mypackage/version.py') as f:  exec(f.read())` in place of `execfile('mypackage/version.py')`. (From http://stackoverflow.com/a/437857/647002)

Comment: The wreak havoc part is not necessarily true ... it will only wreak havoc if your __init__.py file in the package has code imports dependencies (directly or indirectly).

Comment: This worked for Python 2, but with Python 3 I get the error "can't concat bytes to str". Any ideas?

Comment: It seems worth mentioning that django performs an \_\_import\_\_ call [in their setup.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/setup.py). Does '\_\_import\_\_' vs 'import' make this safe? It doesn't appear to be causing them any problems.

Comment: The `__version__` approach is not compatible with setuptools-scm, regretably.

The `pkg_resources` approach is quite good, but will fail horribly while developing a package (since it's not installed).

Comment: The execfile approach is somewhat cool, but it has the disadvantage, that IDE like pycharm won't recognize that `__version__` is actually imported. Well, it's morever a problem on the IDE side, but it is.

Comment: I'm using the approach of having a `mypackage/VERSION` file. I'd love to be able to move that `VERSION` file to the root of the source, so my build scripts do not need to know the package name. Also, my developer would be free with their folder structure and I won'd have to deal with 'underscore vs dash' issues: e.g: my-package is a valid name for the package, but not for the folder.

Comment: If you just want to print the version, you can use `print(pkg_resources.get_distribution(MYPACKAGE))` rather than `print("%s %s" % (MYPACKAGE, pkg_resources.require(MYPACKAGE)[0].version))`

Comment: I used the pkg_resources code u posted to set __version__ inside init. This way from then on you can use mypackage.__version__ and get the version. Thanks

Comment: Since Python 3.8 is now out... There is a solution directly in the standard library `__version__ = importlib.metadata.version('Example')` https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/importlib.metadata.html

Comment: Why do you use `pkg_resources.require("MyProject")[0].version` instead of the more direct `pkg_resources.get_distribution("MyProject").version`? Or even better, when querying from inside the package: `pkg_resources.get_distribution(__package__).version`

Comment: I have a VERSION file that gets automatically populated by a build-automation tool (bamboo). It is there in the source code, yet in the installed package it disappears.  Firstly, should this happen or should it also be present in the installed package (in `site-packages`). In fact, my version and package info are written separately in an egg-info file. Secondly, given that you have a VERSION file, what is the best way to make it readable from `package_name.__version__`? Should you mhave a line in `__init__.py` that reads VERSION?

Answer (score 47):

## example study: `mymodule`

Imagine this configuration:

```
setup.py
mymodule/
        / __init__.py
        / version.py
        / myclasses.py
```

Then imagine some usual scenario where you have dependencies and `setup.py` looks like:

```
setup(...
    install_requires=['dep1','dep2', ...]
    ...)
```

And an example `__init__.py`:

```
from mymodule.myclasses import *
from mymodule.version import __version__
```

And for example `myclasses.py`:

```
# these are not installed on your system.
# importing mymodule.myclasses would give ImportError
import dep1
import dep2
```

## problem #1: importing `mymodule` during setup

If your `setup.py` imports `mymodule` then **during setup** you would most likely get an `ImportError`. This is a very common error when your package has dependencies. If your package does not have other dependencies than the builtins, you may be safe; however this isn't a good practice. The reason for that is that it is not future-proof; say tomorrow your code needs to consume some other dependency.

## problem #2: where's my `__version__` ?

If you hardcode `__version__` in `setup.py` then it may not match the version that you would ship in your module. To be consistent, you would put it in one place and read it from the same place when you need it. Using `import` you may get the problem #1.

## solution: à la `setuptools`

You would use a combination of `open`, `exec` and provide a dict for `exec` to add variables:

```
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from distutils.util import convert_path

main_ns = {}
ver_path = convert_path('mymodule/version.py')
with open(ver_path) as ver_file:
    exec(ver_file.read(), main_ns)

setup(...,
    version=main_ns['__version__'],
    ...)
```

And in `mymodule/version.py` expose the version:

```
__version__ = 'some.semantic.version'
```

This way, the version is shipped with the module, and you do not have issues during setup trying to import a module that has missing dependencies (yet to be installed).

Comment: This seems like the most reasonable solution because it relies only on allowed dependencies.

Comment: Is the concept of package version defined in setup.py file different from the __version__?

Comment: I have 2 issues with using `exec()`. Firstly, using `exec()` is generally discouraged due to potential security issues. Secondly, relative imports done in `__init__.py` won't work and have to be guarded with `if "__name__" in globals()`.

Answer (score 25):

The best technique is to define `__version__` in your product code, then import it into setup.py from there.  This gives you a value you can read in your running module, and have only one place to define it.

The values in setup.py are not installed, and setup.py doesn't stick around after installation.

What I did (for example) in coverage.py:

```
# coverage/__init__.py
__version__ = "3.2"


# setup.py
from coverage import __version__

setup(
    name = 'coverage',
    version = __version__,
    ...
    )
```

UPDATE (2017): coverage.py no longer imports itself to get the version.  Importing your own code can make it uninstallable, because you product code will try to import dependencies, which aren't installed yet, because setup.py is what installs them.

Comment: +1 That's what I use. I'm not sure why @pjeby is so against this method. If you use "from module import version" and version is specified at the top of the source it should only pull that value from the source not matter how broken (or how many dependencies are missing from) the source file.

Comment: @Evan: I'm not sure what you are getting at about "only pull that value from the source".  If the file with `__version__` in it is broken in some way, then your import will also be broken.  Python doesn't know how to only interpret the statements you want.  @pjeby is right: if your module needs to import other modules, they may not be installed yet, and it will be chaotic.  This technique works if you are careful that the import doesn't caues a long chain of other imports.

Comment: @Ned Batchelder I'm pretty sure that, if you put the version before any imports in the source file and only to a 'from module import version' it won't lex any more of the source file than it needs to. Besides, who is going to release broken code? If the package needs dependencies use setuptools or wait for the release of distutils2 later on in the year.

Comment: @Evan, I'm sorry, but you are wrong about importing partial files.  Try putting a print statement at the end of a long module, and import the first variable defined in the file.  The print statement will execute.

Comment: I fell for this, but @pjeby is entirely right: "By the way, DO NOT import your package from your setup.py as suggested in another answer here: it will seem to work for you (because you already have your package's dependencies installed), but it will wreak havoc upon new users of your package, as they will not be able to install your package without manually installing the dependencies first." Ned, would you mind adding a warning to your answer?

Comment: Like @Jan-PhilipGehrcke when I upload a setup.py file like this to PyPI and then `pip install <packagename>`, I get the following error: `ImportError: No module named <packagename>`. Please WARN your readers that you can't run setup.py files like this on environments where the package isn't already installed!

Comment: @hobs actually that error was caused by not having a packages = ["<packagename>"] argument in your `setup()` call.

Comment: This is an anti-pattern, because it prevents the `mypackage/__init__.py` from being able to import any dependencies.  The answer should be updated to show how to do it correctly (e.g., put a separate `version.py` module and then import that from `__init__.py`) so that people don't mistakenly copy the outdated code here.

Comment: could it be used with bumpversion?

Answer (score 20):

Your question is a little vague, but I think what you are asking is how to specify it.

You can define `__version__` like so:

```
__version__ = '1.4.4'
```

...or just put it into the `setup.py` like this:

```py
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name='foobar',
    version='1.4.4',
)
```

...and they you can confirm that `setup.py` knows about the version you just specified:

```
% ./setup.py --version
1.4.4
```

Comment: Years after - working well. Only if `setup.py` exists.

Answer (score 11):

I wasn't happy with these answers... didn't want to require setuptools, nor make a whole separate module for a single variable, so I came up with these.

For when you are sure the main module is in pep8 style and will stay that way:

```
version = '0.30.unknown'
with file('mypkg/mymod.py') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('__version__'):
            _, _, version = line.replace("'", '').split()
            break
```

If you'd like to be extra careful and use a real parser:

```
import ast
version = '0.30.unknown2'
with file('mypkg/mymod.py') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('__version__'):
            version = ast.parse(line).body[0].value.s
            break
```

setup.py is somewhat of a throwaway module so not an issue if it is a bit ugly.

---

Update: funny enough I've moved away from this in recent years and started using a separate file in the package called `meta.py`.  I put lots of meta data in there that I might want to change frequently.  So, not just for one value.

Comment: +1. It's relatively simple, keeps the version number in one place, doesn't require a separate file to contain it, and doesn't impose the python module's import dependencies on setup.py. I wouldn't even bother with the context manager in a program as short-lived as setup.py.

Comment: *Much* nicer than using regex, thanks. You can also use `ast.get_docstring()` with some `.split('\n')[0].strip()` etc to automatically fill out `description` from the source. One less thing to keep in sync

Comment: I would like a generic version that also imports other fields from `__init__.py` (we define `__description__`, `__app_name__`, `__authors__`, etc.)

Comment: How do you import this `meta.py` file in `setup.py`? I don't think it's possible without first importing `__init__.py`, which might contain imports that are not possible during build-time.

Comment: @xjcl, not a problem in my experience. `from foo import meta`   1) Do not import anything of consequence in meta.py  2) Should not do anything radical on import, aka in \__init__.  3) late imports. 
If there is something unavailable, wrap in a try.  You could also load the file manually if absolutely necessary, but would reduce simplicity somewhat.

Comment: If your `setup.py` does `from foo import meta` that also executes code inside of `foo/__init__.py`, which is a problem for me because that indirectly imports `pandas` which I don't want to require for running a _setup script_. Wrapping in a try is ugly and error-prone.

Comment: I gave several alternatives.  Not errorprone.  Shouldn't load a heavy package on import, will affect speed of your CLI --help.  
Another would be to move meta.py up to the same level as setup, although you'll lose access to it in the package.  (Though probably could install it separately with setup.py.)

Comment: Also this answer is a decade old, and even my update is >3.  New hotness is pyproject.toml, may be good for you.

Answer (score 9):

A lot of the other answers are outdated, I believe the standard way to get version information from an installed python 3.10 package is by using importlib.metadata as of [PEP-0566](https://peps.python.org/pep-0566/)

Official docs: https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/importlib.metadata.html

```
from importlib.metadata import version
VERSION_NUM = version("InstalledPackageName")
```

This is simple, clean, and no fuss.

This won't work if you are doing something weird in a script that runs during package installation, but if all you are doing is getting the version number for a version check to show the user in through a CLI --help command, about box, or anything else where your package is already installed and just needs the installed version number this seems like the best solution to me.

Comment: agreed, this is nice, it was provisionally added in python [3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/importlib.metadata.html), but considered stable in [3.10](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/importlib.metadata.html)

Comment: The keyword here is INSTALLED package

Answer (score 7):

With a structure like this:

```
setup.py
mymodule/
        / __init__.py
        / version.py
        / myclasses.py
```

where **version.py** contains:

```
__version__ = 'version_string'
```

You can do this in **setup.py**:

```
import sys

sys.path[0:0] = ['mymodule']

from version import __version__
```

**This won't cause any problem with whatever dependencies you have in your mymodule/__init__.py**

Answer (score 6):

We wanted to put the meta information about our package `pypackagery` in `__init__.py`, but could not since it has third-party dependencies as PJ Eby already pointed out (see his answer and the warning regarding the race condition).

We solved it by creating a separate module `pypackagery_meta.py` that contains *only* the meta information:

```
"""Define meta information about pypackagery package."""

__title__ = 'pypackagery'
__description__ = ('Package a subset of a monorepo and '
                   'determine the dependent packages.')
__url__ = 'https://github.com/Parquery/pypackagery'
__version__ = '1.0.0'
__author__ = 'Marko Ristin'
__author_email__ = 'marko.ristin@gmail.com'
__license__ = 'MIT'
__copyright__ = 'Copyright 2018 Parquery AG'
```

then imported the meta information in `packagery/__init__.py`:

```
# ...

from pypackagery_meta import __title__, __description__, __url__, \
    __version__, __author__, __author_email__, \
    __license__, __copyright__

# ...
```

and finally used it in `setup.py`:

```
import pypackagery_meta

setup(
    name=pypackagery_meta.__title__,
    version=pypackagery_meta.__version__,
    description=pypackagery_meta.__description__,
    long_description=long_description,
    url=pypackagery_meta.__url__,
    author=pypackagery_meta.__author__,
    author_email=pypackagery_meta.__author_email__,
    # ...
    py_modules=['packagery', 'pypackagery_meta'],
 )
```

You must include `pypackagery_meta` into your package with `py_modules` setup argument. Otherwise, you can not import it upon installation since the packaged distribution  would lack it.

Answer (score 5):

Create a file in your source tree, e.g. in yourbasedir/yourpackage/_version.py . Let that file contain only a single line of code, like this:

`__version__ = "1.1.0-r4704"`

Then in your setup.py, open that file and parse out the version number like this:

```
verstr = "unknown"
try:
    verstrline = open('yourpackage/_version.py', "rt").read()
except EnvironmentError:
    pass # Okay, there is no version file.
else:
    VSRE = r"^__version__ = ['\"]([^'\"]*)['\"]"
    mo = re.search(VSRE, verstrline, re.M)
    if mo:
        verstr = mo.group(1)
    else:
        raise RuntimeError("unable to find version in yourpackage/_version.py")
```

Finally, in `yourbasedir/yourpackage/__init__.py` import _version like this:

```
__version__ = "unknown"
try:
    from _version import __version__
except ImportError:
    # We're running in a tree that doesn't have a _version.py, so we don't know what our version is.
    pass
```

An example of code that does this is the "pyutil" package that I maintain. (See PyPI or google search -- stackoverflow is disallowing me from including a hyperlink to it in this answer.)

@pjeby is right that you shouldn't import your package from its own setup.py. That will work when you test it by creating a new Python interpreter and executing setup.py in it first thing: `python setup.py`, but there are cases when it won't work. That's because `import youpackage` doesn't mean to read the current working directory for a directory named "yourpackage", it means to look in the current `sys.modules` for a key "yourpackage" and then to do various things if it isn't there. So it always works when you do `python setup.py` because you have a fresh, empty `sys.modules`, but this doesn't work in general.

For example, what if py2exe is executing your setup.py as part of the process of packaging up an application? I've seen a case like this where py2exe would put the wrong version number on a package because the package was getting its version number from `import myownthing` in its setup.py, but a different version of that package had previously been imported during the py2exe run. Likewise, what if setuptools, easy_install, distribute, or distutils2 is trying to build your package as part of a process of installing a different package that depends on yours? Then whether your package is importable at the time that its setup.py is being evaluated, or whether there is already a version of your package that has been imported during this Python interpreter's life, or whether importing your package requires other packages to be installed first, or has side-effects, can change the results. I've had several struggles with trying to re-use Python packages which caused problems for tools like py2exe and setuptools because their setup.py imports the package itself in order to find its version number.

By the way, this technique plays nicely with tools to automatically create the `yourpackage/_version.py` file for you, for example by reading your revision control history and writing out a version number based on the most recent tag in revision control history. Here is a tool that does that for darcs: http://tahoe-lafs.org/trac/darcsver/browser/trunk/README.rst and here is a code snippet which does the same thing for git: http://github.com/warner/python-ecdsa/blob/0ed702a9d4057ecf33eea969b8cf280eaccd89a1/setup.py#L34

Comment: No need for parsing in setup.py. Just import that python file and use __version__. There are no side effects of importing as this is the only content of that file.

Answer (score 5):

This should also work, using regular expressions and depending on the metadata fields to have a format like this:

```
__fieldname__ = 'value'
```

Use the following at the beginning of your setup.py:

```
import re
main_py = open('yourmodule.py').read()
metadata = dict(re.findall("__([a-z]+)__ = '([^']+)'", main_py))
```

After that, you can use the metadata in your script like this:

```
print 'Author is:', metadata['author']
print 'Version is:', metadata['version']
```

Comment: As I said above, just use str.split :)

Comment: Oh god no.  You're parsing Python in Python?  At the very least, use eval(), child.

Comment: Poor advice slacy, eval should be avoided when so easy.

Comment: I really like this underrated answer because it thinks ahead to include other metadata you might define

Answer (score 4):

Simple and straight, create a file called `source/package_name/version.py` with the following contents:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
__version__ = "2.6.9"
```

Then, on your file `source/package_name/__init__.py`, you import the version for other people to use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from .version import __version__
```

Now, you can put this on `setup.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import re
import sys

try:
    filepath = 'source/package_name/version.py'
    version_file = open( filepath )
    __version__ ,= re.findall( '__version__ = "(.*)"', version_file.read() )

except Exception as error:
    __version__ = "0.0.1"
    sys.stderr.write( "Warning: Could not open '%s' due %s\n" % ( filepath, error ) )

finally:
    version_file.close()
```

Tested this with Python `2.7`, `3.3`, `3.4`, `3.5`, `3.6` and `3.7` on Linux, Windows and Mac OS. I used on my package which has Integration and Unit Tests for all theses platforms. You can see the results from `.travis.yml` and `appveyor.yml` here:

1. https://travis-ci.org/evandrocoan/debugtools/builds/527110800
2. https://ci.appveyor.com/project/evandrocoan/pythondebugtools/builds/24245446

---

An alternate version is using context manager:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import re
import sys

try:
    filepath = 'source/package_name/version.py'

    with open( filepath ) as file:
        __version__ ,= re.findall( '__version__ = "(.*)"', file.read() )

except Exception as error:
    __version__ = "0.0.1"
    sys.stderr.write( "Warning: Could not open '%s' due %s\n" % ( filepath, error ) )
```

You can also be using the `codecs` module to handle unicode errors both on Python `2.7` and `3.6`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import re
import sys
import codecs

try:
    filepath = 'source/package_name/version.py'

    with codecs.open( filepath, 'r', errors='ignore' ) as file:
        __version__ ,= re.findall( '__version__ = "(.*)"', file.read() )

except Exception as error:
    __version__ = "0.0.1"
    sys.stderr.write( "Warning: Could not open '%s' due %s\n" % ( filepath, error ) )
```

---

If you are writing a Python module 100% in C/C++ using Python C Extensions, you can do the same thing, but using C/C++ instead of Python.

On this case, create the following `setup.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import re
import sys
import codecs
from setuptools import setup, Extension

try:
    filepath = 'source/version.h'

    with codecs.open( filepath, 'r', errors='ignore' ) as file:
        __version__ ,= re.findall( '__version__ = "(.*)"', file.read() )

except Exception as error:
    __version__ = "0.0.1"
    sys.stderr.write( "Warning: Could not open '%s' due %s\n" % ( filepath, error ) )

setup(
        name = 'package_name',
        version = __version__,

        package_data = {
                '': [ '**.txt', '**.md', '**.py', '**.h', '**.hpp', '**.c', '**.cpp' ],
            },

        ext_modules = [
            Extension(
                name = 'package_name',
                sources = [
                    'source/file.cpp',
                ],
                include_dirs = ['source'],
            )
        ],
    )
```

Which reads the version from the file `version.h`:

```cpp
const char* __version__ = "1.0.12";
```

But, do not forget to create the `MANIFEST.in` to include the `version.h` file:

```
include README.md
include LICENSE.txt

recursive-include source *.h
```

And it is integrated into the main application with:

```cpp
#include <Python.h>
#include "version.h"

// create the module
PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_package_name(void)
{
    PyObject* thismodule;
    ...

    // https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html#c.Py_BuildValue
    PyObject_SetAttrString( thismodule, "__version__", Py_BuildValue( "s", __version__ ) );

    ...
}
```

References:

1. [python open file error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30700166/python-open-file-error)
2. [Define a global in a Python module from a C API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001239/define-a-global-in-a-python-module-from-a-c-api)
3. [How to include package data with setuptools/distribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522250/how-to-include-package-data-with-setuptools-distribute/)
4. [https://github.com/lark-parser/lark/blob/master/setup.py#L4](https://github.com/lark-parser/lark/blob/a798dec77907e74520dd7e90c7b6a4acc680633a/setup.py#L4)
5. [How to use setuptools packages and ext_modules with the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56244851/how-to-use-setuptools-packages-and-ext-modules-with-the-same-name)
6. [Is it possible to include subdirectories using dist utils (setup.py) as part of package data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924885/is-it-possible-to-include-subdirectories-using-dist-utils-setup-py-as-part-of)

Answer (score 3):

To avoid importing a file (and thus executing its code) one could parse it and recover the `version` attribute from the syntax tree:

```
# assuming 'path' holds the path to the file

import ast

with open(path, 'rU') as file:
    t = compile(file.read(), path, 'exec', ast.PyCF_ONLY_AST)
    for node in (n for n in t.body if isinstance(n, ast.Assign)):
        if len(node.targets) == 1:
            name = node.targets[0]
            if isinstance(name, ast.Name) and \
                    name.id in ('__version__', '__version_info__', 'VERSION'):
                v = node.value
                if isinstance(v, ast.Str):
                    version = v.s
                    break
                if isinstance(v, ast.Tuple):
                    r = []
                    for e in v.elts:
                        if isinstance(e, ast.Str):
                            r.append(e.s)
                        elif isinstance(e, ast.Num):
                            r.append(str(e.n))
                    version = '.'.join(r)
                    break
```

This code tries to find the `__version__` or `VERSION` assignment at the top level of the module return is string value. The right side can be either a string or a tuple.

Comment: That looks clever and complicated :)  It’d be simpler to just have a _version.py file containing one assignment and parse that with open-read-str.split.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I think it's too complex for this situation, but very helpful for understanding how one might approach the problem. I like that it keeps the version number in one place, doesn't require a separate file to contain it, and doesn't impose the python module's import dependencies on the setup script.

Answer (score 3):

There's a thousand ways to skin a cat -- here's mine:

```
# Copied from (and hacked):
# https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/develop/setup.py#L42
def get_version(filename):
    import os
    import re

    here = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    f = open(os.path.join(here, filename))
    version_file = f.read()
    f.close()
    version_match = re.search(r"^__version__ = ['\"]([^'\"]*)['\"]",
                              version_file, re.M)
    if version_match:
        return version_match.group(1)
    raise RuntimeError("Unable to find version string.")
```

Answer (score 2):

Cleaning up https://stackoverflow.com/a/12413800 from @gringo-suave:

```
from itertools import ifilter
from os import path
from ast import parse

with open(path.join('package_name', '__init__.py')) as f:
    __version__ = parse(next(ifilter(lambda line: line.startswith('__version__'),
                                     f))).body[0].value.s
```

Answer (score 2):

Now this is gross and needs some refining (there may even be an uncovered member call in pkg_resources that I missed), but I simply do not see why this doesn't work, nor why no one has suggested it to date (Googling around has not turned this up)...note that this is Python 2.x, and would require requiring pkg_resources (sigh):

```
import pkg_resources

version_string = None
try:
    if pkg_resources.working_set is not None:
        disto_obj = pkg_resources.working_set.by_key.get('<my pkg name>', None)
        # (I like adding ", None" to gets)
        if disto_obj is not None:
            version_string = disto_obj.version
except Exception:
    # Do something
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

deploy package to server and file naming convention for indices packages  :

example for pip dynamic version conversion:

- win:

  - test_pkg-1.0.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
  - test_pkg-1.0.0-py3.6-win-amd64.egg
- mac:

  - test_pkg-1.0.0-py3.7-macosx-10.12-x86_64.egg
  - test_pkg-1.0.0-py3.7-macosx-10.12-x86_64.whl
- linux:

  - test_pkg-1.0.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl

```
from setuptools_scm import get_version

def _get_version():

     dev_version = str(".".join(map(str, str(get_version()).split("+")[0]\
            .split('.')[:-1])))

    return dev_version
```

Find the sample setup.py calls the dynamic pip version matching from git commit

```
setup(
    version=_get_version(),
    name=NAME,
    description=DESCRIPTION,
    long_description=LONG_DESCRIPTION,
    classifiers=CLASSIFIERS,

# add few more for wheel wheel package ...conversion

)
```

Answer (score 2):

For what is worth, I wrote [getversion](https://smarie.github.io/python-getversion/) to solve this issue for one of our projects' needs. It relies on a sequence of PEP-compliant strategies to return the version for a module, and adds some strategies for development mode (git scm).

Example:

```py
from getversion import get_module_version

# Get the version of an imported module
from xml import dom
version, details = get_module_version(dom)
print(version)
```

Yields

```
3.7.3.final.0
```

Why was this version found ? You can understand it from the `details`:

```
> print(details)
Version '3.7.3.final.0' found for module 'xml.dom' by strategy 'get_builtin_module_version', after the following failed attempts:
 - Attempts for module 'xml.dom':
   - <get_module_version_attr>: module 'xml.dom' has no attribute '__version__'
 - Attempts for module 'xml':
   - <get_module_version_attr>: module 'xml' has no attribute '__version__'
   - <get_version_using_pkgresources>: Invalid version number: None
   - <get_builtin_module_version>: SUCCESS: 3.7.3.final.0
```

More can be found in the [documentation](https://smarie.github.io/python-getversion/).

Answer (score 1):

I am using an environment variable as below

VERSION=0.0.0 python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel

In setup.py

```py
import os

setup(
    version=os.environ['VERSION'],
    ...
)
```

For consistency check with packer version, I am using below script.

```sh
PKG_VERSION=`python -c "import pkg; print(pkg.__version__)"`
if [ $PKG_VERSION == $VERSION ]; then
    python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
else
    echo "Package version differs from set env variable"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I created the regex pattern to find version number from setup.cfg `?:[\s]+|[\s])?[=](?:[\s]+|[\s])?(.*)`

```
import re
with open("setup.cfg", "r") as _file:
    data = _file.read()
print(re.findall(r"\nversion(?:[\s]+|[\s])?[=](?:[\s]+|[\s])?(.*)", data))
# -> ['1.1.0']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code to your `__init__.py`:

```
VERSION = (0, 3, 0)


def get_version():
    """Return the VERSION as a string.
    For example, if `VERSION == (0, 10, 7)`, return '0.10.7'.
    """
    return ".".join(map(str, VERSION))


__version__ = get_version()
```

And add this to the `setup.py`:

```
def get_version(version_tuple):
    """Return the version tuple as a string, e.g. for (0, 10, 7),
    return '0.10.7'.
    """
    return ".".join(map(str, version_tuple))


init = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "your_library", "__init__.py")
version_line = list(filter(lambda line: line.startswith("VERSION"), open(init)))[0]
VERSION = get_version(eval(version_line.split("=")[-1]))
```

And finally, you can add the `version=VERSION,` line to the `setup`:

```
setup(
    name="your_library",
    version=VERSION,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue in the following way:

Created a version.py inside my module:

setup.py

```
mymodule/
    / __init__.py
    / version.py
    / myclasses.py
```

version.py

```
__version__ = '1.0.0'
```

setup.py

```
import sys
    
sys.path.insert(0, ("./mymodule"))

from version import __version__
```

I've avoided dependency this way. Of course, I'was inspired by many answers here.

Thank you!