# Define a global in a Python module from a C API

Tags: python, c, global-variables, python-module, python-c-api

I am developing a module for Python using a C API. How can I create a variable that is seen as global from Python?

For example, if my module is `module`, I want to create a variable `g` that does this job:

```
import module
print module.g
```

In particular, `g` is an integer.

## Solution from Alex Martelli

```
PyObject *m = Py_InitModule("mymodule", mymoduleMethods);
PyObject *v = PyLong_FromLong((long) 23);

PyObject_SetAttrString(m, "g", v);
Py_DECREF(v);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [PyObject_SetAttrString](http://docs.python.org/c-api/object.html#PyObject_SetAttrString) in your module's initialization routine, with first argument `o` being (the cast to `(PyObject*)` of) your module, second argument `attr_name` being "g", third argument `v` being a variable

```
PyObject *v = PyLong_FromLong((long) 23);
```

(or whatever other value of course, `23` is just an example!-).

Do remember to decref `v` afterwards.

There are other ways, but this one is simple and general.

Comment: thanks, can you check the full solution that I report in the question?

Comment: @wiso, yep, those 4 lines were exactly what I had in mind (except that you're naming the attribute "L" in the edit and it is "g" above in the original question, but that's no doubt just an oversight).