# How to use setuptools packages and ext_modules with the same name?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-import, setuptools, python-c-api

I got the following file structure for my Python C Extension project:

```
.
├── setup.py
├── source
    ├── cppimplementation
    │   └── fastfile.cpp
    └── fastfilepackage
        ├── __init__.py
        └── version.py
```

And I use the following `setup.py` file:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension

setup(
        name= 'fastfilepackage',
        version= '0.1.1',
        package_dir = {
            '': 'source',
        },

        packages = [
            'fastfilepackage',
        ],

        ext_modules= [
            Extension(
                'fastfilepackage',
                [
                    'source/cppimplementation/fastfile.cpp',
                ]
            )
        ],
    )
```

I install them with:

```
$ pip3 --version
pip 19.1.1 (python 3.6)

$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.7

$ pip3 list
Package                Version      
---------------------- -------------
wheel                  0.33.1        
setuptools             40.8.0        
...

fastfilepackage$ pip3 install .
```

The problem is that when I install it, my Python C Extension module is overridden by `fastfilepackage/version.py` and `fastfilepackage/__init__.py`, i.e, after installing it, I got the following:

```
import fastfilepackage
print( dir( fastfilepackage ) )
# prints ['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', 
#         '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__',
#         'version']
```

i.e., no FastFile class exported by `source/cppimplementation/fastfile.cpp`, but it has the `fastfilepackage/version.py` and `fastfilepackage/__init__.py` files.

This is the installed file structure:

```
.
└── dist-packages
    ├── fastfilepackage
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   └── version.cpython-36.pyc
    │   └── version.py
    ├── fastfilepackage-0.1.1.dist-info
    │   ├── INSTALLER
    │   ├── LICENSE.txt
    │   ├── METADATA
    │   ├── RECORD
    │   ├── top_level.txt
    │   └── WHEEL
    └── fastfilepackage.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

But if I remove the lines `package_dir = { '': 'source', },` and `packages = [ 'fastfilepackage', ],` from my setup file, then, my Python C Extension module is correctly installed:

```
import fastfilepackage
print( dir( fastfilepackage ) )
# prints ['FastFile', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', 
#         '__package__', '__spec__']
```

i.e., it has the FastFile class exported by `source/cppimplementation/fastfile.cpp`, but it does not have the `fastfilepackage/version.py` and `fastfilepackage/__init__.py` files.

This was the installed file structure:

```
.
└── dist-packages
    ├── fastfilepackage-0.1.1.dist-info
    │   ├── INSTALLER
    │   ├── LICENSE.txt
    │   ├── METADATA
    │   ├── RECORD
    │   ├── top_level.txt
    │   └── WHEEL
    └── fastfilepackage.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

How can I put `ext_modules` and `packages` to use the same package name under my `setup.py` without one overriding the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. The first one imported wins. You cannot have scripts/modules/packages/extensions with the same name — one overrides all others.

But you can to have one inside another. Make your extension named `fastfilepackage.fastfilepackage` and you can `import fastfilepackage` to import the Python package and `import fastfilepackage.fastfilepackage` to import the extension; or `from fastfilepackage import fastfilepackage`.

Comment: Can you give-me an example of `setup.py` doing this?

Comment: `Extension('fastfilepackage.fastfilepackage', ['source/cppimplementation/fastfile.cpp',])`

Comment: I did this, but it did not work out of the box. I also had to edit `fastfilepackage/__init__.py` and manually include `from . import fastfilepackage`

Answer (score 2):

As a final solution, I completely removed all Python `*.py` code because they caused the C Extensions code to become 30% slower. Now my `setup.py` become like this:

```py
from setuptools import setup, Extension

setup(
        name = 'fastfilepackage',
        version = '0.1.1',

        ext_modules = [
            Extension(
                name = 'fastfilepackage',
                sources = [
                    'source/fastfile.cpp',
                ],
                include_dirs = ['source'],
            )
        ],
    )
```

File structure:

```
.
├── setup.py
├── MANIFEST.in
├── README.md
├── LICENSE.txt
└── source
    ├── fastfile.cpp
    └── version.h
```

**MANIFEST.in**

```
include README.md
include LICENSE.txt

recursive-include source *.h
```

This is the installed file structure: (No `*.py` files anywhere = 100% performance)

```
.
└── dist-packages
    ├── fastfilepackage-0.1.1.dist-info
    │   ├── INSTALLER
    │   ├── LICENSE.txt
    │   ├── METADATA
    │   ├── RECORD
    │   ├── top_level.txt
    │   └── WHEEL
    └── fastfilepackage.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

I just replaced the `version.py` directly by a C Extensions module attribute:

```cpp
// https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html#c.Py_BuildValue
const char* __version__ = "0.1.1";
PyObject_SetAttrString( thismodule, "__version__", Py_BuildValue( "s", __version__ ) );
```

References:

1. [Define a global in a Python module from a C API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001239/define-a-global-in-a-python-module-from-a-c-api)
2. Original commit: [Deprecated the Python implementation *.py](https://github.com/evandrocoan/fastfilepackage/commit/d0d889a57ed7c3aee9257b42b48064bab904e600)