# Is it possible to include subdirectories using dist utils (setup.py) as part of package data?

Tags: python, installation, distutils, setup.py

Basically my python package is setup like:

```
module
\_examples
  \_folder1
     \_file1.py
     \_file2.py
  \_folder2
    \_file1.py
    \_file2.py
```

Basically I want to just use:

```
package_data  = { 
            'module': ['examples/*'],
  },
```

because my project always has people adding examples and I want it to be easy to list them from within my application.  I can get it work for any FILE within examples, but not re-curse down through sub-directories.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 55):

I believe what you're looking for is something like this for you `setup.py`, which will recursively find any packages in the project, also be sure and include `__init__.py` files to subdirectories for each package you want.

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='MySoftware',
      packages=find_packages()
)
```

Comment: Be careful here, because you might accidentally include test directories, etc. unless you explicitly `exclude=...` these.

Comment: worked in combination with MANIFEST.in for non-python files for me

Answer (score 16):

In my package root folder, I have a `setup.py` file [see doc](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html)
In this file, I have the following code:

```py
from setuptools import setup

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setup(
    name='package name',
    version='0.4.1',
    description='short description',
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url='repository url',
    author='My name',
    author_email='my@e.mail',
    license='MIT',
    packages=['PackageName','PackageName.SubModule'],
    zip_safe=False,
    install_requires=[
        'dependecy1',
    ],
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 3 - Alpha',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7'
    ]
)
```

The interesting part to answer the question, here is :
`packages=['PackageName','PackageName.SubModule'],`

By following this syntax, you can include sub-modules to your main package distribution.

More info about all the others arguments can be found in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html).

Comment: Out of all the answers here, I think this is the cleanest way

Answer (score 8):

You'll have to use a [`MANIFEST.in`](http://docs.python.org/distutils/sourcedist.html#manifest-template) file for that.

I believe you'll want something like this:

```
$ cat MANIFEST.in
recursive-include examples/ *.py
```

Comment: I think you can also directly use Python functions in setup.py to find files and directories, but I can't quite find the exact answer at the moment.

Comment: Hrm, I will have to give it a try as I did:
recursive-include examples *.py

and didn't use the /.  I read that MANIFEST.in is being deprecated though.  I think I may just have to follow the python function call method.

Comment: Oh… Well, if you figure out how to do it with Python, please post here. I'd like to know.

Comment: where is the location of the Manifest.in file? Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can include all the subdirectories.

You just need to pass the below args to setup() function:

```
packages=find_packages()

include_package_data=True
```

Along with this you need to have a MANIFEST.in file, with contents as

```
recursive-include examples *
```

This ensures all the files are recursively included.

If you want to exclude certain extensions specifically, you can do so by specifying exclude array in the `find_packages()` argument.

Ex: To exclude `.txt` files

```
packages=find_packages(exclude=['.txt'])
```

You can read more about `include_package_data` [here](https://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/trunk/setuptools/setuptools.txt).

And also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522250/how-to-include-package-data-with-setuptools-distribute) is another link which tells you when you should not use `include_package_data`

Answer (score 3):

None of the suggested answers worked for me in a similar situation.

I needed to make a distribution with my package, which included several sub-modules in a sub-directory, so that these were the files I needed to go into `sdist`:

```
ipyexperiments/*py
ipyexperiments/utils/*py
```

and no matter what I tried, the subdir `utils`'s modules were not getting included in `sdist`.

What worked for me is leaving `config.py`'s default:

```
# config.py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
[...]
setup(
    packages = find_packages(),
    [...]
)
```

but adding to `MANIFEST.in`:

```
# MANIFEST.in
graft ipyexperiments
```

and everything under `ipyexperiments` was included.

If you don't already have `MANIFEST.in`, create it at the same directory as `config.py`.

I also added to `MANIFEST.in`

```
prune tests
global-exclude *.py[co]
```

to exclude all of `tests` directory and any unwanted `*pyc` and `*.pyo` files anywhere.

Comment: where does your `MANIFEST.in` file live? At the same level as `setup.py` or at the top of the package you're making?

Comment: that's correct. I edited the reply to reflect that. thank you for asking.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of `include` parameter of `find_packages()`:

```py
...
setup(name="module",
      packages=find_packages(include=('module*',)),
...
```

Comment: In my case I had to use `find_packages(include=('module/*',))`

Answer (score 1):

Following what David Wolever said, just to make it a little more clear. If you want to include everything under a sub-directory folder you have to explicitly specify each file in the MANIFEST.in,

`recursive-include examples/ *.py *.png *.sh` etc.....

It would be nice if the manifest.in would just understand 
`examples/` and include everything but oh well.

Comment: It does support including all files below a certain path now with `graft some-dir/`.

Answer (score 0):

All other answers seemed to complicated. This worked with version 9.3.15:

```
package_data  = { 
            'module': ['examples/**'],
  },
```

Note the `**` instead of `*`. No `__init__.py` was required in any folders.

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer that worked for me is to just include all the directories in the packages= option in the setup  call:

```
 packages=[“examples”, “examples/_folder1”, “examples/_folder2”]
```