# How to package perl files in python wheel

Tags: python, perl, setuptools, distutils, python-wheel

We have created a pip wheel file for a package which has a collection of python and perl scripts. Since python packaging will only add the python files to the wheel file what is the best way to package the perl files as well.

This is my project structure

```
.
|____myproject
| |____logging.ini
| |____utils.py
| |____myperlscript.pl
| |____config.py
| |____version.py
| |____scripta.py
| |____scriptb.py
| |____scriptc.py
| |______init__.py
|____test
| |____test_scripts.py
|______init__.py
|____MANIFEST.in
|____README.md
|____setup.py
|____.gitignore
|____Jenkinsfile
```

Comment: Either use [package_data](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+package_data) or [data files](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+data+files).

Answer (score 0):

If you are currently using `setuptools` in the `setup.py` for your project, and making use of `python setup.py bdist_wheel` as the method to generate the `.whl` file, add the following line to the `MANIFEST.in` file which is already present at the root of your project.

```
recursive-include myproject *
```

Naturally, replace `myproject` for the actual top level directory that will include the target `.pl` scripts (or any other file).

As a demo, if your `setup.py` is written approximately like so:

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools import find_packages

setup(
    name='myproject',
    version='0.0.0',
    description='demo package',
    long_description=open('README.md').read(),
    classifiers=[
        'Programming Language :: Python',
    ],
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False,
)
```

Running `python setup.py bdist_wheel` will show output that looks like:

```
...
adding 'myproject/__init__.py'
adding 'myproject/config.py'
adding 'myproject/logging.ini'
adding 'myproject/myperlscript.pl'
adding 'myproject/scripta.py'
adding 'myproject/utils.py'
adding 'myproject/version.py'
adding 'test/__init__.py'
...
```

The files are packaged inside the `.whl`:

```
$ unzip -t dist/myproject-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl 
Archive:  dist/myproject-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
    testing: myproject/__init__.py    OK
    testing: myproject/config.py      OK
    testing: myproject/logging.ini    OK
    testing: myproject/myperlscript.pl   OK
...
```

Installing the resulting `.whl` file in a new environment:

```
$ pip install -U myproject-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl 
Processing myproject-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: myproject
Successfully installed myproject-0.0.0
$ ls env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/myproject/
config.py    logging.ini      __pycache__  utils.py
__init__.py  myperlscript.pl  scripta.py   version.py
```

Also note that if the `MANIFEST.in` method is unwanted, include `package_data={'': ['*']},` argument for the `setup` call should also make it work with the recent versions of `setuptools`.

Further addendum: The `setuptools` package actually has a [`MANIFEST.in`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/v40.8.0/MANIFEST.in) that include this particular syntax, though restricted to specific filename extensions for the files they want to include.  This is clearly a supported option despite some guides/documentation that might suggest otherwise.  In fact, this is a feature [provided by the core `distutils` module](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/sourcedist.html#specifying-the-files-to-distribute) that is shipped with Python by default.  Related questions:

- [Is it possible to include subdirectories using dist utils (setup.py) as part of package data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924885/is-it-possible-to-include-subdirectories-using-dist-utils-setup-py-as-part-of)
- [How to include package data with setuptools/distribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522250/how-to-include-package-data-with-setuptools-distribute)

Comment: [Note: MANIFEST.in does not affect binary distributions such as wheels.](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#manifest-in)

Comment: @phd the documentation is wrong, it does actually work, as I have projects that are packaged in this manner.

Comment: @phd also if you read my updates to this answer, you may come across [this](http://blog.codekills.net/2011/07/15/lies,-more-lies-and-python-packaging-documentation-on--package_data-/) link (via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14159430/2904896)) explaining why your suggestion to use `package_data` doesn't actually work, and `data_files` take a lot more effort to use.

Comment: Both links point to quite an outdated answers ("damn lies" in their own terms). These days the primary distribution format is wheels, and `package_data` works perfectly.

Comment: As for `MANIFEST.in` — your update answer contains `include_package_data=True,` — that makes it work.

Comment: @phd Actually it still needs one more line in order to actually make it work, which is `package_data={'': ['*']},` for the new system, but it does **not** change the fact that the assertion that `MANIFEST.in` does not affect wheels is also wrong.

Comment: Without `include_package_data` it doesn't.