# python open file error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to open some file and I know there are some errors in the file with UTF-8 encoding, so what I will do in python3 is

```
open(fileName, 'r', errors = 'ignore')
```

but now I need to use python2, what are the corresponding way to do this?

Below is my code after changing to codecs

```
    with codecs.open('data/journalName1.csv', 'rU', errors="ignore") as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for line in reader:
            print(line)
```

And file is here https://www.dropbox.com/s/9qj9v5mtd4ah8nm/journalName.csv?dl=0

Comment: is it possible to share the file?

Comment: It is not the problem with the file, a lot of file can cause error, I am just asking how to cope with the error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python 2 does not support this using the built-in open
function. Instead, you have to uses codecs.

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open(fileName, 'r', errors = 'ignore')
```

This works in Python 2 and 3 if you decide you need to switch your python version in the future.

Comment: It is still not correct, "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 2028: invalid continuation byte" there is still error, I am going to add my code and upload file.

Comment: Actually I just copy the lines into another file, there is no error, but for this file, if I used the old way in python3, it can pass, but using codecs.open in python2, there is still error, please help me, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For UTF-8 encoded files I would suggest io module.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import io

f=io.open('file.txt', 'r',  encoding='utf8')
s=f.read()
f.close()
```

Comment: `some errors in the file with UTF-8 encoding` means that it really itsn't a pure UTF-8 file.

Comment: My guess was the OP got an error: "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)" or the like. It happens sometimes with UTF-8 decoded strings. Such an error is usually fixed by encoding in UTF-8, not ASCII.