# read json file with german characters python 2 (ironpython)

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, encoding, ironpython

I am working with Ironpython, so python 2 and to read the .json file with German characters I am using encoding='utf-8' but I get the following error: `open() got an unexpected keyboard argument 'encoding'.`

Here an example of the code:

```
   def get_data(self):
        #Open and read data from json file into dict
        with open(self.file, encoding='utf-8') as j_file:
            data_dict = json.load(j_file)
            return data_dict
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Backporting Python 3 open(encoding="utf-8") to Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971033/backporting-python-3-openencoding-utf-8-to-python-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

python 2.x doesn't support the `encoding` parameter. You must import the `io` module to specify the encoding

[open Function - pythontips](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/open_function.html)

```py
import io

   def get_data(self):
        #Open and read data from json file into dict
        with io.open(self.file, encoding='utf-8') as j_file:
            data_dict = json.load(j_file)
            return data_dict
```

Answer (score 1):

Python 2 also does not support the open function directly.

As seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30700186/12711820

You can use something like this:

```
import codecs
    f = codecs.open(fileName, 'r', errors = 'ignore')
```

Answer (score 1):

The `encoding` argument in `open` was added in Python 3. If you want to use encoding in python 2.x, use the following:

```py
import io.open

f = io.open('file.json', encoding='utf-8')
# Do stuff with f
f.close
```