# How are dependencies managed when developing a python package to be distributed on PyPI?

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

I have a python package whose source looks like this

```
├── MANIFEST.in
├── README.rst
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
└── sqlemon
    ├── connection_strings.py
    └── __init__.py
```

Most of the code is in `__init__.py`, which has the following imports:

```
import os
import sqlemon.connections_strings as sqlcs
import yaml  #This is the problem
```

If we run

```
python setup.py sdist
```

we see the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 2, in <module>
    import sqlemon
  File "/home/danielsank/src/sqlemon/sqlemon/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    import yaml
ImportError: No module named yaml
```

This suggests that the virtualenv in which I work on my project must have all of the project's dependencies installed in order to do development.
I guess that's not unreasonable, but I'm not entirely sure what the workflow should look like because the project's dependencies are listed in `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import sqlemon

version = sqlemon.__version__
project_name = sqlemon.__project_name__

setup(name=project_name,
      # Irrelevant lines removed
      install_requires=[
          'sqlalchemy',
          'alembic',
          'pyyaml',
          'sqlalchemy-schemadisplay'
          ],
)
```

I usually put requirements in `requirements.txt` so the developer can do `pip install -r requirements.txt`, but since the requirements are already in `setup.py` that seems redundant.

Furthermore, after uploading my project to PyPI, when I try to pip install  from pypi, the installation fails unless I already have `pyyaml` installed in my virtualenv.
Obviously this is not the behavior we want; `pyyaml` should install automatically as it is listed in the `install_requires` list in `setup.py`.

What is the recommended workflow for this situation?

Comment: It occurs to me that one option might be to not import my own package in `setup.py`...

Comment: [Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058802/how-can-i-get-the-version-defined-in-setup-py-setuptools-in-my-package)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `setup.py` imports `sqlemon` which imports `pyyaml` (and in principle any other dependencies) so it's impossible to process it without having those dependencies installed.
The reason I had `setup.py` importing `sqlemon` was to get the version number.
A better strategy for the version numbers is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2073599/2665591), which allows us to not import our own project in `setup.py`.