# How can I know if my script is installed or not?

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm developing a python script and the last stable version of this script is installed on my PC (using setuptools).

**How can I know** (from the python source) **that the running script is the installed version or development version.** (If I call `python -m awesomescript` in the repository, the dev version will start otherwise the installed version.)

My only idea is to check if the script file is located under the sitepackages, but that doesn't seem as a "beauty" solution.

---

**UPDATE**

The main goal is to get proper version, using [pbr](https://pypi.org/project/pbr/). The following method can be used to get the version of the script within the code. (Fethced from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2073599/2506522) post.)

```py
import pkg_resources  # part of setuptools
version = pkg_resources.require("MyProject")[0].version
```

However the `pkg_resources.require("MyProject")[0].version` will return the version of the installed variant, which is irrelevant if I run development variant of the script.

Comment: how do you install the "script"?

Comment: Using setuptools, with pbr

Comment: maybe you could make the script print his version to be sure of which one you are running or constrain the dev one to run only in a 'dev' folder of the source  "/path/src/dev"

Comment: I have wrote update regarding versions.