# display __version__ using setuptools.setup values in setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools

I have a packaged project `mytools` which uses setuptools' setup to store its version in a setup.py project file e.g.

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
name='mytools',
version='0.1.0'
)
```

I'd like to get the common `mytools.__version__` feature based on the version value e.g.

```
import mytools
mytools.__version__
>>>'0.1.0'
```

Is there native / simple way in setuptools to do so? Couldn't find a reference to `__version__` in setuptools.
Furthermore, I don't want to store the version in `__init__.py` because I'd prefer to keep the version in its current place (setup.py). 
The many answers to similar questions do not speak to my specific problem, e.g. [How can I get the version defined in setup.py (setuptools) in my package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058802/how-can-i-get-the-version-defined-in-setup-py-setuptools-in-my-package)

Comment: `__version__ = importlib.metadata.version('mytools')`? It is just another variable that you have to define in your code, no magic constants are supplied by setuptools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `__version__` to all top-level modules and packages is an outdated recommendation dating back from [PEP 396](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0396/) which was never actually accepted into a standard, and I do not recommend implementing this idea. Here are some messages raising concerns raised about this idea and its actual usefulness, for example here:

- https://gitlab.com/python-devs/importlib_resources/-/issues/100
- https://gitlab.com/python-devs/importlib_metadata/-/merge_requests/125
- some more that I can't find right now...

With that said...

Such a thing is often solved like the following:

```py
# my_top_level_module/__init__.py

import importlib.metadata

__version__ = importlib.metadata.version('MyProject')
```

**References**:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html
- https://importlib-metadata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#distribution-versions