# How can I add a version/build information to my project and setup.py?

Tags: python, version, versioning, setup.py

There are [several](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2058802/344286) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/458550/344286) about getting the version string into `setup.py`. I have a slightly different set of requirements:

1. I need version (e.g. `1.2.3`) string and a build number (the result of `$ git describe --tags --always HEAD`)
2. I need these versions available in my Flask application (e.g. `app.config['VERSION'] = '1.2.3'` and `app.config['BUILD'] = '1.2.3-33-g93abc32'`
3. I need the version string available in `setup.py`

I don't really care if the version/build strings are [under version control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6786555/344286), though it seems that the version would make sense to have there.

So I guess the question, perhaps, is how do I inject some build information into my project from `setup.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have decided to do is roll with the following:

`setup.py`:

```
# Stuff

import subprocess

__version__ = '1.2.3'
__build__ = subprocess.check_output('git describe --tags --always HEAD'
                                    .split()).decode().strip()

with open('mypkg/_version.py', 'w') as f:
    f.write('''\
# I will destroy any changes you make to this file.
# Sincerely,
# setup.py ;)

__version__ = '{}'
__build__ = '{}'
'''.format(__version__, __build__))

# other stuff

settings.update(
    version=__version__,
# more stuff
)
```

I might use the `re` module to simply find/replace the `__version__` and `__build__` lines, but for now this seems to work just fine.

Comment: I would generate `mypkg/__version__.py` conditionally as a part of creating the source distribution (somewhere before `sdist` command). Make sure that `python setup.py develop` also runs it. The numbers themselves could go to `setup.cfg` to avoid changing setup.py only to bump version.