# single-sourcing package version for setup.cfg Python projects

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

For traditional Python projects with a `setup.py`, there are various ways of ensuring that the version string does not have to be repeated throughout the code base. See [PyPA's guide on "Single-sourcing the package version"](https://packaging.python.org/guides/single-sourcing-package-version/) for a list of recommendations.

Many are trying to move away from `setup.py` to `setup.cfg` (probably under the influence of *PEP517* and *PEP518*; `setup.py` was mostly used declaratively anyway, and when there was logic in `setup.py`, it was probably for the worse.) This means that most the suggestions won't work anymore since `setup.cfg` cannot contain "code".

How can I single-source the package version for Python projects that use `setup.cfg`?

Comment: I would not call PyPA and their guides, and tutorials [_official_](https://discuss.python.org/t/remove-the-authority-from-packaging/1993) (but yes they're the closest to _official_ there is for Python packaging). `setup.cfg` has not much to do with _PEP 517_, _PEP 518_, it existed long before (but yes, I see your point). And you want version 5 of of the PyPA recommendations.

Comment: @sinoroc Thanks a lot for your comment. Feel free to edit the post to make it more correct, I'll approve straight away.

Comment: Sorry for the nit-pick, definitely wasn't necessary. Anyway, doesn't directly answer your question since it uses code in `setup.py`, but this is how I do it in my projects: https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/project_version.html

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this (see below for the project structure used in these examples):

**1.**

`setup.cfg`

```
[metadata]
version = 1.2.3.dev4
```

`src/my_top_level_package/__init__.py`

```
import importlib.metadata
__version__ = importlib.metadata.version('MyProject')
```

**2.**

`setup.cfg`

```
[metadata]
version = file: VERSION.txt
```

`VERSION.txt`

```
1.2.3.dev4
```

`src/my_top_level_package/__init__.py`

```
import importlib.metadata
__version__ = importlib.metadata.version('MyProject')
```

**3.**

`setup.cfg`

```
[metadata]
version = attr: my_top_level_package.__version__
```

`src/my_top_level_package/__init__.py`

```
__version__ = '1.2.3.dev4'
```

**And more...**

There are probably other ways to do this, by playing with different combinatons.

---

***References***:

- https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html

---

Structure assumed in the previous examples is as follows...

```
MyProject
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
└── src
    └── my_top_level_package
        └── __init__.py
```

`setup.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import setuptools

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setuptools.setup(
        # see 'setup.cfg'
    )
```

`setup.cfg`

```
[metadata]
name = MyProject
# See above for the value of 'version = ...'

[options]
package_dir =
    = src
packages = find:

[options.packages.find]
where = src
```

```
$ cd path/to/MyProject
$ python3 setup.py --version
1.2.3.dev4
$ python3 -m pip install .
# ...
$ python3 -c 'import my_top_level_package; print(my_top_level_package.__version__)'
1.2.3.dev4
$ python3 -V
Python 3.6.9
$ python3 -m pip list
Package       Version   
------------- ----------
MyProject     1.2.3.dev4
pip           20.0.2    
pkg-resources 0.0.0     
setuptools    45.2.0    
wheel         0.34.2    
zipp          3.0.0
```

Comment: The `importlib.metadata` variant as the disadvantage that it always gives the version of the _installed_ package, even if you use a checkout of devel master, for example.

Comment: Option (3.) does not work. The package won't install locally using `pip install .` with seemingly unrelated `ModuleNotFoundError`s. When using `version = 1.2.3` in the `[metadata]`, it all works. Might be a pip bug, not sure.

Comment: I wasn't sure because of the `src`-layout thing, but (3) seems to work for me, unless I did something wrong like not properly cleaning the left-over metadata between attempts.

Comment: Ah wait, maybe I did something wrong with the directory layout. Do I _have_ to use a `src` folder?

Comment: I never really understood the issue with not wanting to install the distribution before using it. It has a version, it is a properly packaged project, it is meant to be installed, just install it, even if it is just in _editable_ mode (`pip install --editable .`). Maybe people have a different workflow than mine, which is fair enough, but the packaging itself is 100% correct, and the user is not using it right by choosing not to install it.

Comment: I'll be happy to learn! I've never installed a project as part of my devel workflow: Just `cd` into the folder, edit the files in the tree, and run the tests from there. `import foobar` will then always import the `foobar` folder from the current directory.

Comment: (3) doesn't work for me. When putting my code in `src/foobar`, `pip install .` tells me `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foobar'` -- understandable, too. Maybe I misunderstand `my_top_level_package`?

Comment: It definitely should work without the `src`-layout, and it surprised me by working with the `src`-layout as well. But the `src`-layout is a bit tricky at first, it needs some extra care via the `package_dir` option, so maybe leave it out at first.

Comment: I have no idea how this can work for you. What is `my_top_level_package` in your case. The package name, right?

Comment: I added a full example at the end.

Comment: After some digging, I found the issue. You can reproduce it like that: Add `import numpy` to the top of your `__init__.py`. `pip install .` works fine. Add a dummy `pyproject.toml` to your tree. Failure! Why? Because now, the build happens in an isolated env, and `attr: my_top_level_package.__version__` gets evaluated _before_ dependencies are installed there. :(

Comment: I see, chicken and egg. I would not recommend the version (3) anyway (not that the other ones are ideal either). You could have a variant of (3) with `version = attr: my_top_level_package.meta.version` and the version number in `src/my_top_level_package/meta.py` `version = '1.2.3.dev4'` and the initializer becomes: `import numpy; from . import meta; __version__ = meta.version`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work either. Whenever you access any of `my_top_level_package`, it first goes through the `__init__.py`. You get the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208635/discussion-between-sinoroc-and-nico-schlomer).

Comment: Thank you so much. I was struggling for 3 days, not undersanding why my setup.cfg would fail. This is just because there were quotes in the package name and the version number, and I needed to remove them. Your example gave me the solution !

Comment: `MyProject` must be the folder name correct? Or is it reading `name = MyProject` from setup.cfg?

Comment: @red888 `MyProject` refers to the `name = MyProject` in `setup.cfg`. This is the name of the "distribution package", which is also the name that you should use in `pip install MyProject` for example. The directory name does not matter.

Comment: @sinoroc is it possible somehow for the version to come from an environment variable?

Comment: @red888 It is out of scope for this question but yes. In `setup.py` in the `setuptools.setup()` function call, you could write something like `version=os.getenv('MYPROJECT_VERSION')`.