# Python's argparse to show program's version with prog and version string formatting

Tags: python, version, argparse

What's the preferred way of specifying program name and version info within argparse?

```
__version_info__ = ('2013','03','14')
__version__ = '-'.join(__version_info__)
...
parser.add_argument('-V', '--version', action='version', version="%(prog)s ("+__version__+")")
```

- http://argparse.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/ArgumentParser.html#prog
- http://pymotw.com/2/argparse/
- http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0386/
- http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0396/
- http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3001/

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Yes, that's the accepted way.  From http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#action:

```
>>> parser.add_argument('--version', action='version', version='%(prog)s 2.0')
```

You should of course be embedding the version number in your package in a standard way: [Standard way to embed version into python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458550/standard-way-to-embed-version-into-python-package)

If you're following that method, you have a `__version__` variable:

```
from _version import __version__
parser.add_argument('--version', action='version',
                    version='%(prog)s {version}'.format(version=__version__))
```

For example, that's the method demonstrated at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/commando/0.3.2a:

> ```
> parser.add_argument('-v', '--version', action='version', version='%(prog)s ' + __version__)
> ```

Comment: how would this look like, in a standard way? i see you put your version example of "2.0" verbatim in the argparse code line ...

Comment: Fine, after the edit it is answering the question. Thanks a lot. Still I'm confused about %(var) and {var) though ...

Comment: @type `%(var)` is old `%` string formatting; `{var}` is new `format` string formatting.

Comment: It seems one cannot use a unified string formatting here
`parser.add_argument('-V', '--version', action='version', version="{prog}s ({version})".format(prog="%(prog)", version=__version__))`

Comment: if here is a holy war then in new version you can even use f-string :D version=f'%(prog)s {__version__}'

Answer (score 5):

Just wanted to post another approach. As of Python 3.11, you can get a package's version number as a string using `importlib.metadata`. So if your program is a package with a `pyproject.toml` file then you can get the version number that is defined in that file. The example below get's the version string of a command line tool named genja; where genja is the name of the Python package that is the command line program.

```py
from importlib.metadata import version

parser.add_argument('-v', '--version', action='version', version=version('genja'))
```

Comment: I think it already works with 3.10.

Comment: `importlib.metadata` is available since 3.8, when the package was created in the standard library