# How to version a Python program

Tags: python, version

I'm doing a Python program (for use in a Linux environment) and I want it to support version actualizations of the program. I read somewhere I should add a line like "__ Version __" but I'm not really sure where and how to put it. What I want to achieve is not having to erase my whole program every time I want to install a new version of it. 
thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what are you talking about. Some authors use a *convention* of placing some `__version__` variables in the main files of their programs, but this is not an official convention and the interpreter doesn't look at that. There exist some python's package managers and libraries that are used to handle this(e.g. distutils/setuptools).

Comment: Do i understand you correctly, that you basically want a loader, which checks first if there's a more recent version online and downloads/installs it if so, else it just starts the local version?

Comment: actually what i want is to make my program able to handle versions, so if in the future i want to install a newer version of my program, it will know what i am talking about. I guess i have to add some line which says "this version is .." so that when i install a new version it can notice it

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend you to use `setuptools` instead of manually versioning it. It is the de-facto stanrad now and very simple to use. All you need to do is to create a `setup.py` in your projects root directory:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='your_programms_name',
      version='major.minor.patch',
      packages=find_packages(),
)
```

and then just run:

```
python setup.py sdist
```

and then there will be eggs under your dist folder.

Answer (score 3):

What you actually want to do is make your Python program into [a package using distutils](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/).

You would create a setup.py. A simple example would look something like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(name='foo',
      version='1.0',
      py_modules=['foo'],
)
```

This is the most standard way to version and distribute Python code. If your code is open source you can even register it with the cheese shop^M^M^M^MPyPi and install it on any machine in the world with a simple `pip install mypackage`.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you want to be versioned.

Single modules with independent versions, or the whole program/package.

You could theoretically add a `__version__` string to every class and do dynamic imports, by testing these variables.

If you want to version the main, or whole program you could add a `__version__` string somewhere at the top of your `__init__.py` file and import this string into you `setup.py` when generating packages. This way you wouldn't have to manually edit multiple files and `setup.py` could be left mostly untouched.

Also consider using a string, not a number or tuple. See [PEP 396](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0396/).

Answer (score 1):

If you are only concerned with versions on your local machine, I would suggest becoming familiar with Git.  Information about version control in Git can be found [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control).

If you are concerned with version control on a module that others would use, information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458550/standard-way-to-embed-version-into-python-package).