# Pyinstaller on a setuptools package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, setuptools, python-click

I'm attempting to run PyInstaller on a CLI app I am building in Python using the [Click](http://click.pocoo.org/6/) library. I'm having trouble building the project using PyInstaller. PyInstaller has a document in their GitHub wiki titled [Recipe Setuptools Entry Point](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-Setuptools-Entry-Point), which gives information about how to use PyInstaller with a `setuptools` package, which I'm using for this project. However, it seems it cannot find the base module when I run `pyinstaller --onefile main.spec`.

**My question is: Is the problem simply an issue with the folder structure I have? Does the [Recipe Setuptools Entry Point](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-Setuptools-Entry-Point) assume a certain file structure?**

*Relevant information*

**Pyinstaller output**

```
184 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.3.1
184 INFO: Python: 3.6.4
189 INFO: Platform: Darwin-16.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
193 INFO: UPX is available.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pyinstaller", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 94, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 46, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 791, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 737, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 40, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 26, in Entrypoint
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 582, in get_entry_info
    return get_distribution(dist).get_entry_info(group, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 564, in get_distribution
    dist = get_provider(dist)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 436, in get_provider
    return working_set.find(moduleOrReq) or require(str(moduleOrReq))[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 984, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 870, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'myapp' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

**The `main.spec` file for `main.py`, which is the entrypoint for my CLI app:**

```
block_cipher = None

def Entrypoint(dist, group, name,
               scripts=None, pathex=None, hiddenimports=None,
               hookspath=None, excludes=None, runtime_hooks=None):
    import pkg_resources

    # get toplevel packages of distribution from metadata
    def get_toplevel(dist):
        distribution = pkg_resources.get_distribution(dist)
        if distribution.has_metadata('top_level.txt'):
            return list(distribution.get_metadata('top_level.txt').split())
        else:
            return []

    hiddenimports = hiddenimports or []
    packages = []
    for distribution in hiddenimports:
        packages += get_toplevel(distribution)

    scripts = scripts or []
    pathex = pathex or []
    # get the entry point
    ep = pkg_resources.get_entry_info(dist, group, name)
    # insert path of the egg at the verify front of the search path
    pathex = [ep.dist.location] + pathex
    # script name must not be a valid module name to avoid name clashes on import
    script_path = os.path.join(workpath, name + '-script.py')
    print ("creating script for entry point", dist, group, name)
    with open(script_path, 'w') as fh:
        print("import", ep.module_name, file=fh)
        print("%s.%s()" % (ep.module_name, '.'.join(ep.attrs)), file=fh)
        for package in packages:
            print ("import", package, file=fh)

    return Analysis([script_path] + scripts, pathex, hiddenimports, hookspath, excludes, runtime_hooks)

a = Entrypoint('myapp', 'console_scripts', 'myapp')

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='main')
```

**The contents of the `myapp` script generated when I run `pip3 install --editable .` in my virtual environment:**

```
#!/some/path/to/myapp-cli/venv/bin/python3.6
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'myapp','console_scripts','myapp'
__requires__ = 'myapp'
import re
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('myapp', 'console_scripts', 'myapp')()
    )
```

**And finally, my repository structure:**

```
myapp-cli/
├── README.md
├── myapp
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── main.spec
│   ├── resources
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── functions.py
│   ├── subcommands
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── config
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── cli.py
│   │   ├── create
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── cli.py
│   │   ├── destroy
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── cli.py
│   │   └── switch
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       └── cli.py
│   └── variables.py
├── requirements.txt
└── setup.py
```

**And my `setup.py` file:**

```
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup
import os

base_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)

setup(
    entry_points = '''
        [console_scripts]
        myapp=myapp.main:entry_point
    ''',
    install_requires = [
        'packageone==1.0',
        'packagetwo==2.0',
    ],
    name = "myapp",
    packages=find_packages(),
    setup_requires="setuptools",
    version = "0.1",
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First:** I used a combination of Stephen's answer, and some digging of my own to find the answer. In the end, Stephen's first part did the trick: manually adding / exporting the `PYTHONPATH` variable. You can actually specify this using `pathex` in the `Entrypoint` function like so:

```
a = Entrypoint('myapp-cli',
    'console_scripts',
    'myapp',
    pathex=['/some/path/to/myapp-cli/myapp', '/some/path/to/myapp-cli']
)
```

I didn't end up needing the `myapp.main` after all.

**Second:** I was still having issues with PyInstaller ***not*** producing a single binary. For me, this did the trick:

- Add the *latest* version of PyInstaller to your `requirements.txt` or to your `install_requires` in `setup.py`: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip.
- Also, you can make your `.spec` file with the `--onefile` option in `pyi-makespec` like so: `pyi-makespec --onefile myapp.py`. This will make a `.spec` file that ensures that all of your packages are compiled into the binary.

*In the end, the following spec file did the trick, and I was able to make a fully working binary:*

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None

def Entrypoint(dist, group, name,
               scripts=None, pathex=None, hiddenimports=None,
               hookspath=None, excludes=None, runtime_hooks=None):
    import pkg_resources

    # get toplevel packages of distribution from metadata
    def get_toplevel(dist):
        distribution = pkg_resources.get_distribution(dist)
        if distribution.has_metadata('top_level.txt'):
            return list(distribution.get_metadata('top_level.txt').split())
        else:
            return []

    hiddenimports = hiddenimports or []
    packages = []
    for distribution in hiddenimports:
        packages += get_toplevel(distribution)

    scripts = scripts or []
    pathex = pathex or []
    # get the entry point
    ep = pkg_resources.get_entry_info(dist, group, name)
    # insert path of the egg at the verify front of the search path
    pathex = [ep.dist.location] + pathex
    # script name must not be a valid module name to avoid name clashes on import
    script_path = os.path.join(workpath, name + '-script.py')
    print ("creating script for entry point", dist, group, name)
    with open(script_path, 'w') as fh:
        print("import", ep.module_name, file=fh)
        print("%s.%s()" % (ep.module_name, '.'.join(ep.attrs)), file=fh)
        for package in packages:
            print ("import", package, file=fh)

    return Analysis([script_path] + scripts, pathex, hiddenimports, hookspath, excludes, runtime_hooks)

a = Entrypoint('myapp-cli',
    'console_scripts',
    'myapp',
    pathex=['/some/path/to/myapp-cli/myapp', '/some/path/to/myapp-cli']
)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='myapp',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

I think in the end using something like [Cobra for Golang](https://github.com/spf13/cobra) would work easier since Golang compiles one-file binaries out of the box. However, if you prefer Python, this should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

This error:

> pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'myapp' distribution was not found and is required by the application

indicates that this package is not on `PYTHONPATH`.  I fixed it on Windows with:

```
set PYTHONPATH=.
```

adjust to your OS of choice.

---

In addition to the path problem, there is:

#### In setup.py:

```
setup(
    entry_points = '''
        [console_scripts]
        myapp=myapp.main:entry_point
    ''',
```

#### In main.spec:

```
a = Entrypoint('myapp', 'console_scripts', 'myapp')
```

According to setup.py, it looks like your entry point is `myapp.main` not `myapp`.  So you may need:

```
a = Entrypoint('myapp', 'console_scripts', 'myapp.main')
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me.  I had to add the `egg-info` directory via the `.spec` file.

My call to the `Entrypoint` function looks like this:

```
a = Entrypoint(
        'PrintIt',
        'console_scripts',
        'printit',
        datas=[('plugins/*.egg', 'plugins/'),
               ('../PrintIt.egg-info/*', 'PrintIt.egg-info/')])
```

Answer (score 0):

Something I've noticed is that the [typical way of adding a data file](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle) doesn't work once you've monkey patched Entrypoint in the way Scott Crooks recommends in the [ticked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48893024/1358677). For me, I had to append to the `a.datas` array. In python3, this looks like:

```
...
a = Entrypoint(...)
from pathlib import Path
Path('/tmp/modulename/datafile.txt').write_text(Path('datafile.txt').read_text()))
a.datas.append('datafile.txt', '/tmp/modulename/datafile.txt', 'DATA')

pyz = PYZ(...)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

After much searching, this error is generally due to attempting to access your project's package's metadata (i.e. version being the primary one).

Package metadata is typically accessed using `pkg_resources` or the older `distutil`, either explicitly, or often hidden in other packages (usually attempting to access the package version).  Starting with Python v3.8 it will also be available in the stdlib within `importlib.metadata`.

If this is the case, you likely need to include some or all of the files in a `mypackage.egg-info` folder, especially the file `PKG_INFO`, but it may require them all.

There are multiple ways to do this, here are several I like:

---

#### 1. If you are using a `script.spec` file, you can update the `datas=` line to include this info, per Charles answer:

```py
a = Analysis(['myscript.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\path\\to\\mypackage'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('mypackage.egg-info/*','mypackage.egg-info')],
```

---

#### 2. Create a custom hook file, put it in a directory, and add the directory as a custom hooks directory at the command line.

Create a `hook-mypackage.py` hook file, with the following very simple, and pretty elegant, lines:

```py
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import copy_metadata

datas = copy_metadata('md2mat')
```

I put this into a new `hooks` folder in my root package/repo folder, then added the following to my pyinstaller command:

```sh
pyinstaller -F -y --additional-hooks-dir=hooks myscript.py
```

It works pretty well, and assuming the `copy_metadata` function is well maintained as we change over from older metadata packages to the new importlib.metadata, it should work well through future Python updates.

---

#### 3. Add additional data files directly at the command-line

This might be my favorite, if I could get it working...

```sh
pyinstaller --add-data <SRC;DEST> myscript.py
```

This option `--add-data` shows up in the help output (`pyinstaller --help`), and indicates the format of the argument should be SRC;DEST for Windows, so I **think** it must match the `datas=` format from the other methods, but I couldn't get it to work.

The closest I think I got to the right format were the following:

```py
pyinstaller -F -y --add-data "mypackage.egg-info/*;mypackage.egg-info"
pyinstaller -F -y --add-data="mypackage.egg-info/*;mypackage.egg-info"
```

These would compile, but the resulting exe would just run with no output.

The `--add-data` option is missing from the [PyInstaller Documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/man/pyinstaller.html#description), but shows up when running `pyinstaller --help-commands`.