# ModuleNotFoundError with package from PyPi

Tags: python, module, pypi

I uploaded a package on PyPi using twine, and it went fine.
Now I'm trying to install that package and importing it into a script.

According to pip the module is already installed correctly:

```
PS C:\Users\alber> pip install ethbotutils
Requirement already satisfied: ethbotutils in c:\users\alber\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (1.1)
```

But when I try to import it in a script or in a IDE or in Python IDLE i get:

```
>>> import ethbotutils
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import ethbotutils
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ethbotutils'
```

This is the pyproject.toml file (stored in the project root):

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

And this the setup.py file (stored withing the package directory):

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='ethbotutils',
    version=1.0,
    packages=["."],
    install_requires=["requests~=2.25.1", "PyYAML~=5.4.1"],
    python_requires=">=3.6"
)
```

**EDIT:**

What @a_guest suggested seems to be working: if I import a script present in the package, like "bot_utils" everything works, but it still doens't when I try to import the whole package by its name. How can I fix that?

Comment: Try `python -m pip install ethlib`. Most likely `pip` and `python` don't belong to the same installation.

Comment: Tried, same behaviour

Comment: What is the name of your project? There is no project named [`ethlib` on pypi](https://pypi.org/project/ethlib/). Also could you share the content of your `setup.py` or `pyproject.toml` files?

Comment: That is because I deleted the package. I am really fed up with how python works with imports and modules atm, but I will try again someday

Comment: You should really share the content of your `setup.py` file. My feeling is that you have something like `setup(name='ethlib', packages=find_packages(), ...)`, and then on your local disk the actual folder containing the package is named differently than `ethlib`. So if you did for example `setup(name='ethlib', packages=['foo'], ...)`, then `ethlib` is the name under which the *project* will be identified on PyPI but `foo` is the actual *package* that it contains (so you'd need to `import foo`). Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62951928/3767239) for more information.

Comment: @a_guest thanks for your help man, let's give it a try. I updated the question with what you requested (beware that I also changed the package's name)

Comment: Okay, so apparently you put all `.py` modules inside the same directory where the `setup.py` script is located? Instead, just create a folder next to `setup.py`, called `ethbotutils` and then put all Python files there (except the setup script). Then in `setup.py` you need to specify `packages=["ethbotutils"]`. This tells setuptools to create a *distribution* called `ethbotutils` which contains/ships a *package* of the same name which you can then import; i.e. `import ethbotutils` or `from ethbotutils.bot_utils import xyz`.

Comment: Many thanks, not it works flawlessly. If you make an answer with a recap I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *name* of a distribution (the `name` parameter of `setup`) determines how a [distribution](https://packaging.python.org/glossary/#term-Distribution-Package) (or project) is identified within the Python ecosystem; this includes the [Python Package Index](https://pypi.org/), where the distribution will be located at the URL `https://pypi.org/project/<name>/`.

This is distinct from the actual [package(s)](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-package) that a distribution contains (the `packages` parameter of `setup`). It is these packages that are made available when installing a distribution (e.g. via `pip`).

So as an example, if the `setup.py` file contains the following specification

```py
setup(
    name='foo',
    packages=['bar'],
    ...
)
```

then this will create a *distribution* named `foo` which installs a *package* named `bar`; i.e. after doing `pip install foo`, the content of that distribution (the package) can be accessed via `import bar`. Typically the name of a distribution and the top-level package should coincide in order to avoid conflicts with other distributions which might get installed into the same virtual environment (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62951928/3767239) for more information).

For the specific example of the OP, this means that the `setup.py` file should contain the following specification:

```py
setup(
    name='ethbotutils',
    packages=['ethbotutils'],
    ...
)
```

In order for the setup to work, all relevant Python modules need to be placed inside a local folder `ethbotutils` which exists next to the `setup.py` file.