# Why does my python package list its version as 5.0.6?

Tags: python, versioning, python-packaging

I'm trying to follow the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458550/standard-way-to-embed-version-into-python-package) regarding version controlling a package I'm writing. For some reason the version always comes back as '5.0.6' instead of '1.0.0' as expected.

To try and get to the bottom of this I've made a simple package with the following structure / files:

```
\
    \VersioningExperiments\
        __init__.py
        _version.py
```

Where `__init__.py` looks like this:

```
from _version import __version__
```

and `_version.py` looks like this:

```
__version__ = '1.0.0'
```

When I sit at the root and run the following commands I get `5.0.6` instead of `1.0.0`:

```
python
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import VersioningExperiments
>>> VersioningExperiments.__version__
'5.0.6'
```

If I comment out that lint from `__init__.py` I get:

```
AttributeError: module 'VersioningExperiments' has no attribute '__version__'
```

So where on earth is the `5.0.6` coming from?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `from ._version import __version__`?

Comment: Yes, that was the magic trick I discovered as per my answer below.

Comment: If you add that as an answer with an explanation as to _why_ it fixes it, I'll accept yours as the answer.

Comment: No, you're right, your answer already solves it. I mean, for a deeper explanation one could just check [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) or [the top SO question on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, just in case anyone else runs into this, I got it:

```
>>> import _version
>>> _version.__version__
'5.0.6'
>>> _version.__file__
'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\_version.py'
```

The simplest fix I could find is to alter `__init__.py` in `Test` to this:

```
from ._version import __version__
```