# Using environment variables in `pyproject.toml` for versioning

Tags: python, version, setuptools, pyproject.toml

I am trying to migrate my package from `setup.py` to `pyproject.toml` and I am not sure how to do the dynamic versioning in the same way as before. Currently I can pass the development version using environment variables when the build is for development.

The `setup.py` file looks similar to this:

```
import os

from setuptools import setup

import my_package


if __name__ == "__main__":
    dev_version = os.environ.get("DEV_VERSION")
    version = dev_version if dev_version else f"{my_package.__version__}"
    
    setup(
        name="my_package",
        version=version,
        ...
    )
```

Is there a way to do similar thing when using `pyproject.toml` file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using the return value of a python function as the value for version field in pyproject.toml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76081078/using-the-return-value-of-a-python-function-as-the-value-for-version-field-in-py)

Comment: Also this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76043070

Comment: @sinoroc Thank for the references but I want to manage everything in one place i.e. `pyproject.py` and not to have the `setup.py` file

Comment: Not possible in `pyproject.toml` as far as I know. -- You can of course write a plugin (for *setuptools* or any other build back-end) whose job it is to read environment variables and whose configuration would be in `pyproject.toml`. --- Currently, without having to code anything, what I linked is your best bet as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative that might be worth considering for your use case, if you use Git, is to use [`setuptools_scm`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools_scm). It uses your git tags to perform dynamic versioning. Your pyproject.toml would look something like this:

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "setuptools-scm"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[tool.setuptools_scm]
"version_scheme" = "post-release"
"local_scheme" = "no-local-version"
"write_to" = "mypackage/version.py"

[tool.setuptools.package-dir]
mypackage = "mypackage"

[project]
name = "mypackage"
...
dynamic = ["version"]
```

Answer (score 5):

At the time that I write this answer, the most genuinely valid approach on how to do that is to go ahead and write your `pyproject.toml` [as you normally would](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/declaring-project-metadata/), but instead of having a `version = "..."` field you add a `dynamic = ["version"]`.

Then you can keep a very minimal `setup.py` file which only resolves the dynamic value of version. For example:

```ini
# pyproject.toml
[project]
name = "hello-world"
readme = "README.md"
authors = [...]
dependencies = [...]
dynamic = ["version"]

[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta:__legacy__"
# The difference between `__legacy__` and the regular `build_meta`
# is that `__legacy__` does the equivalent of
# `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))`.
# This allows you to `import` your modules from the `CWD`.
# If you don't like using `__legacy__` you can
# manually add `CWD` to `sys.path` inside your `setup.py`.
```

```py
# setup.py
import os
from setuptools import setup

import my_package

dev_version = os.environ.get("DEV_VERSION")

setup(
  version=dev_version if dev_version else f"{my_package.__version__}"
)
```

These are my remarks about this approach:

- Setuptools allows you to keep all your static metadata/configuration parameters in [`pyproject.toml`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html) and at the same time use logic to compute all the dynamic parts in [`setup.py`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/references/keywords.html).
  [Setuptools docs explicitly say](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/references/keywords.html):

  > Metadata and configuration supplied via `setup()` is complementary to ... the information present in ... `pyproject.toml`.

  It is important however to remember to write `dynamic = [...]` in accordance with the [spec](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/declaring-project-metadata/#dynamic) to allow `setuptools` to overwrite any value that can be specified via the `[project]` table.
- `setup.py` is only deprecated as a "runnable CLI tool" that can be invoked directly with `python setup.py ...`. But it is still a perfectly valid configuration file in the same way that `conftest.py` is a valid configuration file for `pytest` and `noxfile.py` is a configuration file for `nox` (you usually don't call `python conftest.py` or `python noxfile.py`...).
  One evidence for this is article https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html written by one of the authors of PEP 621 (which stablishes the `[project]` table in `pyproject.toml`) and maintainer of `setuptools`.
- Note that I used in the example `build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta:__legacy__"` instead of `build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"`. This happens because `__legacy__` tries to emulate the "side-effect" behaviour of running `python setup.py ...`, [i.e. to add `CWD` to `sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#command-line). If you don't like that, you can manipulate `sys.path` explicitly in your `setup.py` file before the relevant imports.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted something similar.

Unfortunately, toml does not support environment variables and I don't think it wants to, ever.

I've experimented a bit with custom build backend wrappers, and sifting through the layers of setuptools (and setuputils3).

My conclusion is that there is no simpler solution than to write a short build script to dynamically edit the pyproject.toml file...

This kind of thing:

```
#!/bin/bash

#fix version - as toml doesn't support environment vars...
sed -i -e "s/.*version.*/version=\"${DEV_VERSION}\"/g" pyproject.toml

#build python source and binary packages
python3 -m build
```

For your other case (non-development) you can "dynamically" pull in the version as described by someone else in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74514742/4126317

Comment: This is similar to the solution I used where instead of changing the `pyproject.py` file, I change the `my_package/__init__.py` file using sed. Why do you think that toml does not want to support environment variables?

Comment: I currently have an opened PR for `setuptools` to add that capability https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/pull/3885

Comment: @Ilya Awesome, hope it gets accepted! In answer to your question, I just inferred it from [this](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml/issues/255#issuecomment-62277325).

Answer (score 0):

So I found this inside the setuptools docs for [dynamic metadata](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html#dynamic-metadata);

Set up your version to be a dynamic property under the project section:

```
[project]
name = "my_package"
authors = [
    {name = "Joe Bloggs", email = "joseph_bloggy_blogss@email.com"},
]
description = "My package description"
readme = "README.rst"
classifiers = [
     "foo :: bar",
]
dependencies = [
    "foo",
]
dynamic = ["version"]
```

Then add an `attr` inside the dynamic setup tools config:

```
[tool.setuptools.dynamic]
version = {attr = "my_package.VERSION"}
```

`my_package.VERSION` will be the VERSION attribute inside your packages `__init__.py` file.