# Using values generated by python scripts in dynamic fields in pyproject.toml

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

I am trying to find a way of using values generated by python scripts inside the pyproject.toml. For example let's consider we have a function `random_version`. I am using setuptools for package building.

```py
import random

def random_version():
    rand_ver = random.randint(1,10)

    return rand_ver
```

Now there is a `version` field in pyproject.toml file, the output of `random_version` function is used. For now my idea is to write a script that edits the pyproject.toml file and put the random value in version field. Is there any better approach to do it?

Comment: It depends on the build back-end. You should specify in your question which build back-end you are using. Is it *setuptools*, *Poetry*, or something else?

Comment: It's setuptools

Answer (score 1):

First make sure to set the [`version` as `dynamic` in the `pyproject.toml` file](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/declaring-project-metadata/#dynamic):

`pyproject.toml`

```ini
[build-system]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
requires = ["setuptools"]

[project]
name = "MyProject"
# ...
# version field should not be set here, but listed as dynamic
dynamic = [ "version" ]
```

Then you need a `setup.py` script for the `version` only:

`setup.py`

```py
import setuptools
import random

def random_version():
    rand_ver = random.randint(1,10)
    return rand_ver

setuptools.setup(
    version=random_version(),
    # everything else is in `pyproject.toml`
)
```

Comment: It didn't work. The version is set as 0.0.0 all the time. That random_version() function is not used.

Comment: Works as expected for me. -- What commands did you run? Was there any kind of error message or warning message?

Comment: [project]
---
dynamic = ["dependencies", "version", "readme"]

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
namespaces = true
where = ["mymodule1"]

[tool.setuptools.dynamic]
dependencies = {file = ["requirements.txt"]}
readme = {file = ["README.md"], content_type="text/markdown"}                                                                 ###

Comment: This is how it looks like. It doesn't give any error message. Just ignores the setup.py and I think it uses default version 0.0.0.

Comment: This is not readable in the comments. Either post a new question that you can link here (and @-mention my user name), or edit your current question. -- So you have a `name` somewhere? -- I created a project with only the 2 files with the content exactly as in my answer and `pip install`, `pip wheel .` and so on all work perfectly as expected. I recommend you do the same to exclude any other possible parasitic issue.