# Using the return value of a python function as the value for version field in pyproject.toml

Tags: setuptools, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

I am using the *setuptools* build back-end with `pyproject.toml` configuration to create Python packages. My package version is dynamic, for now I am setting a `__version__` attribute in `__init__.py` and read it in `pyproject.toml`.

`pyproject.toml`

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "setuptools-scm"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "pkg1"
authors = [
    {name = "tad", email = "tad@gmail.com"},
]
description = "my pkg desc"
requires-python = ">=3.9"
dynamic = ["dependencies", "version", "readme"]

[tool.setuptools.dynamic]
dependencies = {file = ["requirements.txt"]}
readme = {file = ["README.md"], content_type="text/markdown"}
version = {attr = "__version__"}
```

`__init__.py` of pkg1

```py
def get_version():
    # some critiria to generate a valid version name
    return version

__version__ = get_version()
```

But I want to move `get_version()` from `__init__.py` and put it somewhere else, also I should be able to call that function to fill the version field in `pyproject.toml`. Can someone help me understand how the `pyproject.toml` should be modified to do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76043070 -- and I recommend: `__version__ = importlib.metadata.version('pkg1')`, or skip `__version__` completely if possible.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I would do (some unrelated details omitted for brevity and clarity with ellipsis `...`):

`pyproject.toml`

```ini
[build-system]
# ...

[project]
name = "pkg1"
# ...
dynamic = ["version", "..."]

[tool.setuptools.dynamic]
# ...
# No version here!
```

`setup.py`

```py
import setuptools

def get_version():
    version = "0.0.0"
    # Compute the version string here...
    return version

setuptools.setup(
    version=get_version(),
)
```

`pkg1/__init__.py`

```py
import importlib.metadata

__version__ = importlib.metadata.version('pkg1')
# Where `pkg1` is the name of the distribution package, not the import package.
```

Personally, I would skip the `__version__` entirely if possible. In a lot of cases it is not necessary at all. If someone wants to know the version string of your library `pkg1`, they can fetch it themselves with the same code `importlib.metadata.version('pkg1')`. Because if you have it in your `__init__.py` then it is always computed at import time, even though it might never be used at all.